# Integration with a variable in the terminals.

Tags: integration

I know that in general, if we integrate over some defined values of $x$ and $y$ we find that, for a function $f(x,y)$
$$\iint f(x,y) \ dxdy=\iint f(x,y) \ dydx.$$
However, if we were to integrate, for example, from $y=0$ to $y=2$ and from $x=y$ to $x=\alpha y$, then is it not the case that, for some function
$$\int_0^2\int_y^{\alpha y}f(x,y) \ dxdy=\int_y^{\alpha y}\int_0^2f(x,y) \ dydx.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try this with $f(x,y)=1$?  Calculate each of the integrals in your bottom equation, and notice that you do not get the same thing.  The thing on the left should be a constant, while the thing on the right will be a function of $y$ (unless $\alpha=1$, which is boring because then the integrals are identically zero).

This will, in general, be true no matter what $f$ you choose (unless you pick $f=0$, which is kind of boring).  Therefore, your equation is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\iint_R f(x,y) \ dxdy=\iint_R f(x,y) \ dydx$$
1) Both integrals should cover the same region $R$.

2) Outer limit(s) should not be functions of inner integral variable(s).

Then, when you interchange variables, you may not be able to represent region $R$ with a single set of limits, i.e., it may be $R=R_1+R_2$.  For example, in your case:

When $0<\alpha<1$: 
$$\int_0^2\int_y^{\alpha y}f(x,y) \ dxdy=\int_{0}^{2}\int_{x/\alpha}^{x}f(x,y) \ dydx+\int_{2}^{2\alpha}\int_{x/\alpha}^{2}f(x,y) \ dydx$$
When $\alpha>1$, you may get different set of limits.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true in general. When $$y \le x \le ay$$ we have $$\frac{x}{a} \le y \le x$$ ( assuming $a \ne 0$).